# Calculate the double integral over a region

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the double integral of $f(x,y)$ over the triangle indicated in the following figure:
[image]

$f(x,y)= 18ye^x$

I tried to follow take $x$ limits from 0 to 4 and y from 0 to 3 but that did not worked. I know that i have to take y limits as x values but i did not know how to do it

Comment: In this case, you have a straight line and a point as the endpoints for $x$.  Can you see a way to create limits for $y$ based on a fixed $x$ value?  Perhaps start by defining the boundary lines by their equations in $y=mx+b$ form...

Comment: See the answer to your other question.  In this case it will be best to do $\int(\int f(x,y)\,dy)\,dx$.  For the inner integral you will need to find values of $y$ when $x$ is constant.  So draw a line on your diagram as I suggested before, only this time the line will be $x=\hbox{constant}$ which is. . . ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take x and y one by one, first we fix x, then check what value of y would be.

as the graph says, when x is fixed, y is from x/4 to 3x/4

so the integral is

$$\int f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^4\int_{x/4}^{3x/4}18ye^x\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: that did not give me a right answer

Comment: oh no it is the RIGHT ANSWER i just forgot about the negative sign thanks

Answer (score 0):

The shaded region is not rectangular.

First, we need to determine the $y$ bounds of the region.  They are simply found by point-slope or slope-intercept form, the elementary math method to determine the equations of the lines.  Then, observe that the bounds of integration are $\frac{x}{4} \leq y \leq \frac{3x}{4}$ and $0 \leq x \leq 4$.  Then, we write

$$\int_0^{4}\int_{x/4}^{3x/4} 18ye^{x}\,dy\,dx$$

Finally, evaluate the $y$-integral and then, the $x$-integral since the bounds depend on $x$.

Another approach is to determine the $x$ bounds, fixing $y$.  Then, construct two double integrals since the $x$ bounds depend on three functions, namely $x = \frac{4y}{3}$, $x = 4y$ and $x = 3$.  Think of how you can get two double integrals from the region.

Comment: The first is correct but the second is not.  Draw extra lines on the diagram as I suggested [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699872).